# how to enable php pdo driver for Postgres on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: php, pdo

I installed php 7.2 and php 7.3 on Ubuntu 18.04, and created a php file to log on to and insert data into the Postgres database.  My script responded  "could not find driver."

Research turned up that I have to edit the php.ini files and enable the extensions for Postgres and PDO.  Below are all the extension= lines in the php.ini files.  The closest I could find are the pdo lines shown below.

```
extension=pdo_pgsql
extension=pgsql
```

So I edited the php.ini files and removed the semi-colons from each of those lines to enable them.  Then I restarted Apache2:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

But I still get "could not find driver."

This is the entire listing of extensions from the php.ini files.  Which other extensions do I need to enable to allow PDO access to Postgres?

php.ini 7.3

```
;extension=bz2
;extension=curl
;extension=fileinfo
;extension=gd2
;extension=gettext
;extension=gmp
;extension=intl
;extension=imap
;extension=interbase
;extension=ldap
;extension=mbstring
;extension=exif      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
;extension=mysqli
;extension=oci8_12c  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
;extension=odbc
;extension=openssl
;extension=pdo_firebird
;extension=pdo_mysql
;extension=pdo_oci
;extension=pdo_odbc
extension=pdo_pgsql
;extension=pdo_sqlite
extension=pgsql
;extension=shmop
```

---

php.ini 7.2

```
;extension=bz2
;extension=curl
;extension=fileinfo
;extension=gd2
;extension=gettext
;extension=gmp
;extension=intl
;extension=imap
;extension=interbase
;extension=ldap
;extension=mbstring
;extension=exif      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
;extension=mysqli
;extension=oci8_12c  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
;extension=odbc
;extension=openssl
;extension=pdo_firebird
;extension=pdo_mysql
;extension=pdo_oci
;extension=pdo_odbc
extension=pdo_pgsql
;extension=pdo_sqlite
extension=pgsql
;extension=shmop
```

This is the php logon script (the logon credentials are replaced with dummy values here because I can't reveal them):

```
<?php

$params = [
    'host' => '[IP Address]',
    'user' => '[username]',
    'pwd' => '[password]',
    'db' => '[dbname]'
];

$dsn = sprintf('pgsql:host=%s;dbname=%s;user=%s;password=%s',
    $params['host'],
    $params['db'],
    $params['user'],
    $params['pwd']);

try {
    $dsn = sprintf('pgsql:host=%s;dbname=%s;unix_socket=%s',
        $params['host'], $params['db'], $params['sock']);
    $opts = [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION];
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $params['user'], $params['pwd'], $opts);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
} catch (Throwable $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Then I edited the two .ini files and added ".so" at the end of each of the two lines and restarted Apache2, but I still get the same error message.

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you're missing the `php-pgsql` library, run the following commands and it should start working (keep the changes for the php.ini files):

```
sudo apt install php-pgsql
sudo service apache2 reload
```

I do not have Ubuntu which means the library names could be different.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I'm working on this now and I'll post back.

Comment: I did that and still get the error "could not find driver."  Also, there is no pdo_pgsql.so or pgsql.so file in the extensions directory /usr/lib/php/20180731.  I did php -i | grep pdo_pgsql.so and it returns nothing.

Comment: Did you saw the library being installed? As I said I do not have Ubuntu so I am not able to search for the right library name, try to use apt-cache search php-*` and look for pgsql. (Official docs https://www.php.net/manual/en/pgsql.installation.php says I was right about it)

Comment: I did see the library being installed.  The apt-cache instruction and I see "php7.3-pgsql - PostgreSQL module for PHP" and but nothing on pdo_pgsql.  I need pdo, maybe there is a separate install for that, but I haven't seen any instructions for a separate install.

Comment: Try to install that `php7.3-pgsql` package, I think it does install PDO somehow, I might be wrong. If it does not install then search for it like `apt-cache search php-pdo` or so .... and install that one

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  The answer to this question is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56408731/php-pdo-for-postgres-could-not-find-driver.  Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Oh yup I was assuming you enabled the extension in the right way, even if my help didn't help you would be nice if you accept my answer so far is the only one in your post. I will add the enable modules there :) for future references

Comment: Thanks for comments and your help.  I chose yours as best answer and upvoted it too!  Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks to you, I am glad to help a little bit

Comment: This almost got me there, I had to additionally do `a2enmod proxy_fcgi setenvif` and `a2enconf php7.4-fpm` and then `service apache2 reload`.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what others said, try

```
sudo phpenmod pdo_pgsql
```